# Move to next EditText on click on Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

This is a form a user needs to submit. It contains: Title, Description, Price, Country, Province, Email address and a Save Button.
I would all the EditTexts and the Save Button to be horizontal, and a Next Button at the bottom.
When a user enters a title then presses Next Button the Description Input Text appears. Enter some description, press Next and Price appears, and so on until the Save Button.
I will be displaying 6 images on the screen that will take most of the view, so I want the Edit Texts to be at the bottom.

I can't think of a better way of doing this besides using a horizontal scroller, but I really don't want to scroll.

EX:
The Title is visible and the rest of the EditTexts are not. When a user enters the title and clicks Next Button the Title disappears and the Description EditText appears and so on until the end.
I only want to show on EditText at a time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagesLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image6"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_multi_selection"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/blue5"

        android:text="Images" />
</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_right"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imagesLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Country"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_state_province"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="State/Province/Region"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="City"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Your Contact Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are asking how to make the edittext change the focus of the screen to the next control?

Comment: @SteelToe I want to show only one EditText at a time. EX: Title is visible, the others are not. When user enters the title then clicks Next Button the Title disappears and Description EditText appears and so on.

Comment: Why don't you use the setVisibilty method on the views, passing in View.Gone to hide the view and then using View.Visible to show the view. See the documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a listener to your "next button". Edit the sample code so to include your buttons id. Then create variables for your text view. Also finding them by id. Then use the variables to check the visibility of the text view. If it is visible then hide it and show the next view.

```
 final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             if (tv1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                 tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 return;
             }
             if (tv2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                 tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 return;
             }
             //continue as in the example for all your text views.

            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_multi_selection"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/blue5"
            android:text="Images" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:hint="Country"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_state_province"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:hint="State/Province/Region"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="City"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your Contact Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Post"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

try this i removed the horizontal scroll bar because it was of no use. try add a scroll view for better ux. and in the .java you can check if the edittext is empty if not empty set the edittext view to be gone example `edittext.setVisibilty(View.GONE);` then set the next edittext to be visible. example `edittext2.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);`